# extracting observations from matrix where columns and rows match a "key"

Tags: r

Given a matrix `m` how can I create a `TRUE`/ `FALSE` or `1` / `0` matrix where the columns and rows match some "key" in a data frame?

My goal is to assign a `1` or `0` to the location in the matrix where the columns match the `cols` and the rows match the `rows` in the `colsrows_df`. Then essentially just extract the observations where this is true or paste them into the `colsrows_df` next to the correct columns.

The below forloop just creates diagonally `1`'s and `0`'s

```
     m <- matrix(runif(30), nrow = 20, ncol = 20)

    dimnames(m) <- list(c(paste0("ID", 1:5, "_2000"), paste0("ID", 1:5, "_2001"), paste0("ID", 1:5, "_2002"), paste0("ID", 1:5, "_2003")),
                        c(paste0("ID", 1:5, "_2000"), paste0("ID", 1:5, "_2001"), paste0("ID", 1:5, "_2002"), paste0("ID", 1:5, "_2003")))




    cols <- colnames(m)
    rows <- rownames(m)

    library(tidyr)

    library(dplyr)
    colsrows <- cbind(cols, rows)

# Here I just separate the rows/cols and then add an extra year and paste them back together

    colsrows_df <- colsrows %>%
      data.frame %>%
      separate(cols, c("id_col", "year_col"), "_", remove = FALSE) %>%
      separate(rows, c("id_row", "year_row"), "_", remove = FALSE) %>%
      mutate(year_row_plus_1 = as.numeric(year_row) + 1,
             rows = paste0(id_row,"_", year_row_plus_1)) %>%
      select(cols, rows)


    colsrows_df

    for(i in 1:nrow(colsrows)){
      m[i, ] <- colnames(m) == colsrows_df$cols
      m[, i] <- rownames(m) == colsrows_df$rows
    }
    m
```

EDIT:

This seems to "solve" the problem however I am not sure how robust it is.

```
ids <- colsrows_df[colsrows_df$cols %in% colnames(m) & 
                     colsrows_df$rows %in% rownames(m), ]

res <- melt(m[as.matrix(colsrows_df[colsrows_df$cols %in% colnames(m) & 
                          colsrows_df$rows %in% rownames(m), ][2:1])])

cbind(ids, res)
```

Comment: can you make a small reproducible example (not 20 by 20 but maybe 2 by 2) and also include your desired output.

Comment: Sure, will do so now.

Comment: Do you want `colnames(m)[i] %in% colsrows_df$cols` instead of `colnames(m) == colsrows_df$cols`? And I guess you need to loop over both rows and columns.

Comment: I think that puts me a step closer to the solution, yes.

Comment: The expected output is when the intersection of the rownames and colnames match the colsrows_df then give a 1, else give 0. So for each column there will be just one "1" the rest will be zeros (hopefully this makes sense)

Comment: I get `ID5_2004 ` in `colsrows_df` but there is no row or column with that name in `m`. Can you check?

Comment: That gets created when I apply `mutate(year_row_plus_1 = as.numeric(year_row) + 1`. Not all rows/columns will intersect/match, the majority of them will.

Comment: so not all columns would have 1 then? in some columns there could also be all 0's. ?

Comment: Yes, my appologies for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think can you first filter `colsrows_df` with `rownames` and `colnames` which are actually present in `m` then change the order of columns, convert to matrix , use it to subset `m` and change those values to 1.

```
m[as.matrix(colsrows_df[colsrows_df$cols %in% colnames(m) & 
                       colsrows_df$rows %in% rownames(m), ][2:1])] <- 1
```

Then convert remaining ones to 0

```
m[m != 1] <- 0
```

Comment: Now I just need to modify this a little and extract the values where the `1` occurs

Comment: @user113156 once you change values to 1 wouldn't `which(m == 1)` or `which(m == 1, arr.ind = TRUE)` give what you want ?